# Is it possible to use all camel components using HotSpot

Tags: quarkus

I noticed that there are only a few camel extensions available to use in native mode. I am wondering if it's still possible to use the other camel components if you don't compile to native? And if, is it usefull to go that way, or should we for example stick to spring boot?

Answer (score 1):

Note that all Camel extensions might not need a Quarkus one. Basically, a Quarkus extension is needed if we need to tune the Camel extension for GraalVM (add reflection declarations for instance). The interesting thing is that you can even do the work manually to make your Camel extension work in GraalVM mode and then report back so that we create a proper extension for all future use.

In JVM mode, all Camel extensions should work flawlessly. If you encounter an issue, please open a GitHub issue and we will take a look at it.

About if using Quarkus in JVM mode is worth it, I'm obviously partial but I think the Quarkus approach is beneficial even in JVM mode. You still have some of the benefits of better boot time and reduced memory usage. Obviously, depending on your application, they might not be important to you.